# Automatic Export Query information to excel

Tags: sql-server

I need to export the result of one query to excel, I want this process to be done every week so i need it to be automatic, i tried with bcp utility but it only generates a csv file and the column names are not exported, only the information, how can i do it giving a nice format to the excel file and that it to be automatic every week?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create an [SSIS package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), to export the data.  The package is then scheduled with the [SQL Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent).

There are lots of guides that can help you develop both steps.  Two you could start with:

1. [SSIS - Export from SQL Server to Excel](http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-excel/)
2. [How to schedule a SQL Agent Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx)

**PLEASE NOTE:** The *Express* and *LocalDb* editions of SQL Server do not include the SQL Agent.  As an alternative you could use [Window's task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Answer (score -1):

To export data from `SQLServerNativeClient` in Visual Studio Server explorer execute excel and exported from the following path.
This is for `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` but other data source like this.

```
Excel2010/Data/FromOtherSource/FromDataConnectionWizard/OtherAdvanced/SQLServerNativeClient11/SelectOrEnteraServerName: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB/
```